# r creating older siblings alive at marriage of the ego

Tags: r, counting

Here is a better version of my former question: I have a data set of mothers (`mid`), children (`id`), and the birth (`born`), death (`dead`), and marriage date (`Marriage_Date`) of these children. `ord` gives the order of birth, `tstart` and `tstop` the year of entry, exit of the individual under observation. `tstart3` and `tstop3` indicate the age of the person at each interval under observation. the time of observation is in survival analysis format, meaning it is cut at every year (cut in spells).

Of the children I want to create one column with the time varying number of older siblings, if possible male and females separately, that are alive when the ego (`id`) is under observation (and in consequence when he or she is marrying - which is the event of my analysis). 
The dataframe itself should not be changed as it is the required format for survival analyses. what should change is the number of siblings alive at tstop for each individual. If a sibling is born to an already existing child, the new column oldersiblings gets a + 1, the next plus one adds up until the id of the mother changes again. if a sibling dies, - 1 until the next on is born.

So, in my view, the solution must be something like a for loop that groups by `mid` (and `id`?)

Here is the data extract in dput format:

```
structure(list(id = c("1799939", "1799939", "1799939", "1799939", 
"1799939", "1799939", "1799939", "1132576", "1132576", "1132576", 
"1132576", "1132576", "1132576", "1132576", "1132576", "1112778", 
"1112778", "1112778", "1112778", "1112778", "1112778", "1112778", 
"1112778", "1112778", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", 
"1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", 
"1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", 
"1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", 
"1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", 
"1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1667687", "1933509", 
"1933509", "1933509", "1933509", "1933509", "1933509", "1933509", 
"1933509", "1933509", "1097672", "1097672", "1097672", "1097672", 
"1097672", "1097672", "1097672", "1097672", "1097672", "1097672", 
"1097672", "1097672", "1097672", "1097672", "1039958", "1039958", 
"1039958", "1039958", "1039958", "1039958", "1039958"), mid = c("1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", 
"1004212", "1004241", "1004241", "1004241", "1004241", "1004241", 
"1004241", "1004241"), born = c(1813.5698630137, 1813.5698630137, 
1813.5698630137, 1813.5698630137, 1813.5698630137, 1813.5698630137, 
1813.5698630137, 1815.48767123288, 1815.48767123288, 1815.48767123288, 
1815.48767123288, 1815.48767123288, 1815.48767123288, 1815.48767123288, 
1815.48767123288, 1818.01095890411, 1818.01095890411, 1818.01095890411, 
1818.01095890411, 1818.01095890411, 1818.01095890411, 1818.01095890411, 
1818.01095890411, 1818.01095890411, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 
1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1820.2131147541, 1824.33333333333, 
1824.33333333333, 1824.33333333333, 1824.33333333333, 1824.33333333333, 
1824.33333333333, 1824.33333333333, 1824.33333333333, 1824.33333333333, 
1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 
1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 
1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 
1826.89589041096, 1826.89589041096, 1828.28142076503, 1828.28142076503, 
1828.28142076503, 1828.28142076503, 1828.28142076503, 1828.28142076503, 
1828.28142076503), dead = c(1863.97808219178, 1863.97808219178, 
1863.97808219178, 1863.97808219178, 1863.97808219178, 1863.97808219178, 
1863.97808219178, 1844.07103825137, 1844.07103825137, 1844.07103825137, 
1844.07103825137, 1844.07103825137, 1844.07103825137, 1844.07103825137, 
1844.07103825137, 1890.85205479452, 1890.85205479452, 1890.85205479452, 
1890.85205479452, 1890.85205479452, 1890.85205479452, 1890.85205479452, 
1890.85205479452, 1890.85205479452, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 
1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1871.81643835616, 1902.33150684932, 
1902.33150684932, 1902.33150684932, 1902.33150684932, 1902.33150684932, 
1902.33150684932, 1902.33150684932, 1902.33150684932, 1902.33150684932, 
1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 
1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 
1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 
1862.01643835616, 1862.01643835616, 1852.22950819672, 1852.22950819672, 
1852.22950819672, 1852.22950819672, 1852.22950819672, 1852.22950819672, 
1852.22950819672), Marriage_Date = c(1837.8602739726, 1837.8602739726, 
1837.8602739726, 1837.8602739726, 1837.8602739726, 1837.8602739726, 
1837.8602739726, 1838.3397260274, 1838.3397260274, 1838.3397260274, 
1838.3397260274, 1838.3397260274, 1838.3397260274, 1838.3397260274, 
1838.3397260274, 1844.91256830601, 1844.91256830601, 1844.91256830601, 
1844.91256830601, 1844.91256830601, 1844.91256830601, 1844.91256830601, 
1844.91256830601, 1844.91256830601, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1850.10684931507, 1850.10684931507, 
1850.10684931507, 1850.10684931507, 1850.10684931507, 1850.10684931507, 
1850.10684931507, 1850.10684931507, 1850.10684931507, 1857.06301369863, 
1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 
1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 
1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 1857.06301369863, 
1857.06301369863, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), start3 = c(0, 
0.430136986301477, 1.43013698630148, 2.43013698630148, 3.43013698630148, 
4.43013698630148, 5.43013698630148, 0, 0.512328767123336, 1.51232876712334, 
2.51232876712334, 3.51232876712334, 4.51232876712334, 6.51232876712334, 
5.51232876712334, 0, 0.989041095890343, 1.98904109589034, 2.98904109589034, 
3.98904109589034, 4.98904109589034, 5.98904109589034, 6.98904109589034, 
7.98904109589034, 0, 0.786885245901658, 1.78688524590166, 2.78688524590166, 
3.78688524590166, 4.78688524590166, 5.78688524590166, 6.78688524590166, 
7.78688524590166, 8.78688524590166, 9.78688524590166, 10.7868852459017, 
11.7868852459017, 12.7868852459017, 13.7868852459017, 14.7868852459017, 
15.7868852459017, 16.7868852459017, 17.7868852459017, 18.7868852459017, 
19.7868852459017, 20.7868852459017, 21.7868852459017, 22.7868852459017, 
23.7868852459017, 24.7868852459017, 25.7868852459017, 26.7868852459017, 
27.7868852459017, 28.7868852459017, 29.7868852459017, 30.7868852459017, 
31.7868852459017, 0, 0.666666666666742, 1.66666666666674, 2.66666666666674, 
3.66666666666674, 4.66666666666674, 5.66666666666674, 6.66666666666674, 
7.66666666666674, 0, 0.104109589041173, 1.10410958904117, 2.10410958904117, 
3.10410958904117, 4.10410958904117, 5.10410958904117, 6.10410958904117, 
7.10410958904117, 8.10410958904117, 9.10410958904117, 10.1041095890412, 
12.1041095890412, 11.1041095890412, 0, 0.718579234972594, 1.71857923497259, 
2.71857923497259, 3.71857923497259, 5.71857923497259, 4.71857923497259
), stop3 = c(0.430136986301477, 1.43013698630148, 2.43013698630148, 
3.43013698630148, 4.43013698630148, 5.43013698630148, 6.2904109589042, 
0.512328767123336, 1.51232876712334, 2.51232876712334, 3.51232876712334, 
4.51232876712334, 5.51232876712334, 6.85205479452065, 6.51232876712334, 
0.989041095890343, 1.98904109589034, 2.98904109589034, 3.98904109589034, 
4.98904109589034, 5.98904109589034, 6.98904109589034, 7.98904109589034, 
8.90160940190117, 0.786885245901658, 1.78688524590166, 2.78688524590166, 
3.78688524590166, 4.78688524590166, 5.78688524590166, 6.78688524590166, 
7.78688524590166, 8.78688524590166, 9.78688524590166, 10.7868852459017, 
11.7868852459017, 12.7868852459017, 13.7868852459017, 14.7868852459017, 
15.7868852459017, 16.7868852459017, 17.7868852459017, 18.7868852459017, 
19.7868852459017, 20.7868852459017, 21.7868852459017, 22.7868852459017, 
23.7868852459017, 24.7868852459017, 25.7868852459017, 26.7868852459017, 
27.7868852459017, 28.7868852459017, 29.7868852459017, 30.7868852459017, 
31.7868852459017, 32, 0.666666666666742, 1.66666666666674, 2.66666666666674, 
3.66666666666674, 4.66666666666674, 5.66666666666674, 6.66666666666674, 
7.66666666666674, 7.77351598173527, 0.104109589041173, 1.10410958904117, 
2.10410958904117, 3.10410958904117, 4.10410958904117, 5.10410958904117, 
6.10410958904117, 7.10410958904117, 8.10410958904117, 9.10410958904117, 
10.1041095890412, 11.1041095890412, 12.1671232876713, 12.1041095890412, 
0.718579234972594, 1.71857923497259, 2.71857923497259, 3.71857923497259, 
4.71857923497259, 5.94808743169392, 5.71857923497259), ord = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), tstart = c(1831.5698630137, 
1832, 1833, 1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1831.48767123288, 1832, 1833, 
1834, 1835, 1836, 1838, 1837, 1836.01095890411, 1837, 1838, 1839, 
1840, 1841, 1842, 1843, 1844, 1838.2131147541, 1839, 1840, 1841, 
1842, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 
1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 
1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 1842.33333333333, 1843, 
1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1844.89589041096, 1845, 
1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1854, 1855, 1857, 
1856, 1846.28142076503, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1852, 1851), 
    tstop = c(1832, 1833, 1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1837.8602739726, 
    1832, 1833, 1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1838.3397260274, 1838, 
    1837, 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841, 1842, 1843, 1844, 1844.91256830601, 
    1839, 1840, 1841, 1842, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 
    1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 
    1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 
    1869, 1870, 1870.2131147541, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 
    1848, 1849, 1850, 1850.10684931507, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 
    1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857.06301369863, 
    1857, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852.22950819672, 1852
    )), .Names = c("id", "mid", "born", "dead", "Marriage_Date", 
"start3", "stop3", "ord", "tstart", "tstop"), row.names = c(NA, 
-87L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("mid", 
"id"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(66:79, 15:23, 7:14, 24:56, 
    0:6, 57:65, 80:86), group_sizes = c(14L, 9L, 8L, 33L, 7L, 
9L, 7L), biggest_group_size = 33L, labels = structure(list(mid = c("1004212", 
"1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004212", "1004241"
), id = c("1097672", "1112778", "1132576", "1667687", "1799939", 
"1933509", "1039958")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("mid", 
"id"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("mid", "id")))
```

One of my many trials was this:

```
fam <- fam[
  with(fam, order(mid, ord)),
]

#fam <- fam[ which(fam$mid > 1004211 & fam$mid < 1004246 ) ,]

fam <- group_by(fam, mid, id) 

for(i in 1:nrow(fam)){
  fam$older_sibs_alive[i] <- length(which(fam$mid==fam$mid[i]) & fam$id==fam$id[i] & lag(fam$dead) < fam$Marriage_Date[i])
}
```

Of course, not what I want.

Is there any of who how has a solution in mind? Thanks a lot.

Comment: At a glance you want to `rank` each individual by age among siblings at each cross section (I.e. `by` family, time). I'm not at a computer but you should find answers by searching "rank by group r"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution, does what I think you are asking:

## Code

```r
library(dplyr)

fam %>%
  ungroup() %>% # data provided was in a grouped_df, ungroup the data for a clean slate
  select(sibling.id = id, 
         mid, 
         sibling.born = born, 
         sibling.dead = dead, 
         ord) %>% # select only the fields that we need to know about siblings
  distinct(sibling.id, 
           mid, 
           sibling.born, 
           sibling.dead, 
           sibling.ord = as.numeric(ord)) %>% # select distinct siblings
  inner_join(fam, by = c("mid" = "mid")) %>% # join siblings onto the original fam dataset
  group_by_at(vars(one_of(colnames(fam)))) %>% # group by all the columns in the original fam dataset
  summarise(n_older_siblings = #count the records where
              sum(sibling.id != id & # the row is a sibling
                    sibling.born <= tstop & # the sibling has been born
                    sibling.dead > tstop & # the sibling is not yet dead
                    sibling.ord < as.numeric(ord))) %>% # the sibling was born first
  select(-contains("sibling.")) -> fam # remove the sibling columns
```

## Explanation

For each record in the `data.frame` we need to know about the siblings of the individual. So first we create a new `tibble` with just information about each individual: id, mid, born, dead and ord.

```r
fam %>%
  select(sibling.id = id, 
         mid, 
         sibling.born = born, 
         sibling.dead = dead, 
         ord) %>% 
  distinct(sibling.id, 
           mid, 
           sibling.born, 
           sibling.dead, 
           sibling.ord = as.numeric(ord))
```

We join this new sibling `tibble` onto the original `fam` `data.frame`. The result is a much larger `tibble` where each row is a unique combination of individual, time, and individuals related to the individual. If an individual has 5 siblings then each row from `fam` will now be 6 rows.

```r
inner_join(fam, by = c("mid" = "mid"))
```

We want to collapse this back down into the original number of rows. We do this by grouping and summarizing the data. We group by all of the columns in the original `fam` `data.frame` and summarise with the sum of a bunch of boolean expressions that encode the conditions you want to count.

```r
group_by_at(vars(one_of(colnames(fam)))) %>% 
  summarise(n_older_siblings =
              sum(sibling.id != id & 
                    sibling.born <= tstop & 
                    sibling.dead > tstop &
                    sibling.ord < as.numeric(ord))) %>%
```

the `group_by_at` allows us to specify with code the columns we want to group by and the specific `vars(one_of(colnames(fam)))` implementation means we group by each of the column names in the `fam` `data.frame`.

Finally, deselect the columns which contain "sibling." because these are the ones we created in the sibling `tibble` at the start.

Comment: @ Eumenedies: it does work indeed. I will carefully study your explanations so that I manage alone next time. I want to thank you very much.

Comment: @BenMat - Please accept this answer if it does what you need to mark your question as closed.